# xcode: Using a UIImageView subclass with NSTimers

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm creating a program where an image of a bird continuously falls from the top of the screen (like "raining" birds). In order to have an NSTimer for each individual bird, I made a UIImageView subclass (called "BirdUIImageView"). However, I'm not sure how to implement the code correctly--where to put what, etc.

Here is the code I have in ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "BirdUIImageView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController {

    BirdUIImageView *_myImage;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    //IMAGE CREATOR TIMER
    createImagesTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(createImages) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}


  //CREATES AN IMAGE
-(void) createImages {  
    srand(time(NULL));
    int random_x_coordinate = rand() % 286;
    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(random_x_coordinate, 0.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f);
    BirdUIImageView *myImage = [[BirdUIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flake.png"]];
    myImage.opaque = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myImage];
    _myImage = myImage;

}
```

And here is the code I have in BirdUIImageView.m. I'm totally at a loss as to what to do in this file, but I made an attempt:

```
#import "BirdUIImageView.h"



@implementation BirdUIImageView  


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //FALLING BIRDS TIMER
    moveObjectTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(moveObject) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

//FALLING BIRDS MOVER
-(void) moveObject {

    _myImage.center = CGPointMake(_myImage.center.x, _myImage.center.y +1);

}
```

Comment: There's a lot of standard methods to animate view position nicely, do not use NSTimer for that

Comment: If I use those animate methods, would I be able to recall at some point later on the position of each falling bird image? (This will eventually be a game where I have to "catch" the objects in a basket image, so I'll need to recall the positions).

I was under the impression that I have to move them position-by-position in order to get that to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remove the `viewDidLoad` and `moveObject` methods from your `BirdUIImageView` class, and then try this code below on your `ViewController.m` class. You can play around with the timers settings, to have your desired effect:

On `ViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    createImagesTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5
                                                         target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(createImages)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                        repeats:YES];
}


  //CREATES AN IMAGE
-(void) createImages {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int random_x_coordinate = rand() % 286;
    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(random_x_coordinate, 0.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f);
    BirdUIImageView *myImage = [[BirdUIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flake.png"]];
    myImage.opaque = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myImage];
    _myImage = myImage;

    [self move];
}


-(void)move {

    //FALLING BIRDS TIMER
    moveObjectTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(moveObject) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}


//FALLING BIRDS MOVER
-(void) moveObject {

    _myImage.center = CGPointMake(_myImage.center.x, _myImage.center.y +1);

}
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks so much for the help! Finally getting it to work.

Comment: No problem. I'm really glad I could help :-)